# Applying Colour To Open-GL Texture

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I have a 2D texture that I want to reuse instead of having different textures each time for different colours. So what I wanted to know is can you apply a colour to that texture and if so how?

Disco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can blend a texture together with material-color (and even color of lights). Take a look at this site, especially the parts about GLMaterial and the blend-function:

> http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm